# Decl has a package access level but no -package-name was passed

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to implement newly added access specifier **package**

```swift
public class PackageDemoLibrary {
    public init() {}
    
    public var publicVariable = ""
    package var packageVariable = ""
}
```

but it's saying Decl has a package access level but no -package-name was passed.

As per documentation: A new flag -package-name is passed down to a commandline invocation, as follows. [Read more here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0386-package-access-modifier.md#package-names)

```
swiftc -module-name Engine -package-name gamePkg ...
swiftc -module-name Game -package-name gamePkg ...
swiftc -module-name App -package-name appPkg ...
```

I'm not sure how can I add -package name in to my SPM Package.

Anyone know how can I get rid of this error

Comment: It works for me. Can you show a [mcve] of the steps, starting with "creating a new SPM project using `swift package init`", needed to reproduce this?

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for the response, I followed below steps
1. mkdir PackageDemoLibrary,
2. cd PackageDemoLibrary,
3. swift package init,
     simply added this to my Xcode project as local package dependency

Comment: Oh you are building it with the Xcode build system? I'll try that.

Comment: Yes, but currently it's not allowing me to declare this inside my SPM class, when I try to declare a var with package it says Decl has a package access level but no -package-name was passed

Comment: it understands what does this mean but don't how can pass -package-nam, I think it may be done through swiftc, btw I'm just learning

Comment: I still cannot reproduce. Both the SPM package and the Xcode project that has the SPM package as a dependency compile successfully.

Comment: I noticed another thing that this variable complains when I mark my class open or public, in either 3 cases(internal, private, file private) compiling successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your *Package.swift* file and check the version of your `swift-tools-version`. It should be on the first line.

Since the `package` modifier was introduced in [Swift 5.9](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-5.9-released/), check if you're using `swift-tools-version` in a version greater than `5.9`.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the Xcode but somehow my swift-tools-version was 5.8. 
with 5.9 it worked